# Why is meta the only site that appears on my account tab?

Tags: support, status-completed, linked-accounts

[On my meta account tab I only see meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/169859/pubby8?tab=accounts)

[On other sites I see everything except meta.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/964135/pubby8?tab=accounts)

Why is this happening?

**I know my accounts are associated**, because I'm using the same OpenID and everything else is the same.

If I go to the flair tab on meta I see this: (which is odd because it shows my other sites correctly)

[image: meta flair]

Clicking it it takes me to my [correct profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/75f8bbba66c0463492d5a8fc369ddba3).

Comment: @S.L.Barth Whoops! That's what I meant. Thanks.

Comment: You also have two network profiles, one for [meta](http://stackexchange.com/users/760820?tab=accounts), and one for [everything else](http://stackexchange.com/users/286976?tab=accounts). It looks like your meta account is actually separate, even though you are using the same OpenID.

Comment: What do you see when you click `my logins` in your profile (in Meta versus one of your other sites)?

Comment: @jonsca "Unable to load popup" on meta, a few e-mails on SO. I accidentally made a second account (forgot old e-mail) and it was merged to my original, not sure if that affects anything.

Comment: As long as both emails are on there, I think everything is wrangled together.  Try again with Meta, as that's the one that's goofing stuff up, so you may have an openID that you started by accident on that one.

Comment: @jonsca I still am unable to get `my logins` information, but if I logout it shows the same e-mails I use on SO and others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, Stack Exchange sees them as two different users. The network profile shown in your Meta Stack Overflow's user profile is https://stackexchange.com/users/760820, while the network profile shown in your Stack Overflow's user profile is https://stackexchange.com/users/286976.

My network profile, shown in all the SE sites, is https://stackexchange.com/users/79630.

Comment: Why is my flair the same?

Comment: @Pubby8 - because you have less than 200 rep on MSO so it doesn't count towards this version of the combined flair.

Comment: @ChrisF Maybe I don't understand, but shouldn't 2 different users have different flair and profile info? My meta flair links to my correct account.

Comment: @Pubby8 I'm not sure I follow you now. AFAIK "Flair" refers to your combine reputation across the sites. With less than 200 rep on MSO that won't contribute. The two pages linked to above are both you but are separate.

Comment: @ChrisF So I am 2 users whose sites are all associated? I updated my question which explains what I see with the flair.

Comment: @Pubby8 - no one else, other than moderators, can see the `flair` tab on your profile

Answer (score 2):

Your AccountId wasn't set properly on meta, a deadlock issue that happened back when your accounts were merged.  Apologies this took so long, I never saw this question before it had an accepted answer, [but did see this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159995/never-received-fez-hat-due-to-bad-account-linking-requesting-proper-account-li).

You're now all set, effective immediately.