# Never received fez hat due to bad account linking - requesting proper account linking

Tags: bug, status-completed, linked-accounts, winter-bash-2012, merge-accounts

For some reason my meta account hasn't been linked properly to my other accounts for quite some time now. It is sort of half-linked as some things work (such as Convention badge), but others don't.

The fez hat is one of those cases that doesn't seem to work for me, as I asked a question on meta with 3 upvotes a few days ago and haven't gotten the hat yet.

Anyway, I asked about this before: [Why is meta the only site that appears on my account tab?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109945/why-is-meta-the-only-site-that-appears-on-my-account-tab) Which explained what was the problem, but I never requested it to be fixed until now.

**Could please someone merge [my meta account](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/169859/pubby) with [my network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/286976/pubby)?** I don't think it's possible for me to do it myself as "my logins" says "unable to load popup" when I click on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed your account status in the meta database (an update went to deadlock central over a year ago).

Hats (awarded on a schedule, wait a bit) and anything else account related should behave properly now.  If you have *any* account issues lingering, please ping me here and we'll take care of it.

Comment: Thanks! I still don't see Meta [on accounts tab here](http://stackexchange.com/users/286976/pubby?tab=accounts) which might be a lingering issue.

Comment: @Pubby - yes indeed, aggregation of the same data, pushed and updated but cache time is ~10 minutes