# Why is Stack Overflow the only account shown in my reputation tab?

Tags: support, reputation, user-accounts

In Stack Exchange, it lists all my different communities properly.  However, when I look at my [reputation tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/129567/tony?tab=reputation) I can only see Stack Overflow.  I'd like to see my reputation in all the communities, like e.g. [this guy](https://stackexchange.com/users/315778/michael-durrant?tab=reputation).

Note: my Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow IDs are different, is there some bug [like this other guy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109945/why-is-meta-the-only-site-that-appears-on-my-account-tab)?

Edit:

I just tried to edit my Profile & Settings in Stack Overflow.  When I pressed "Save and copy changes to all public communities" I got an error message

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
>
> - This email address is already registered. If it belongs to you, log in above or visit our account recovery page to get access to this
>     account.

But I'm already logged in.  This is one of several little things that make me think my accounts are partially but not correctly linked.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that graph bottoms out at 200, so you have to have at least 200 rep on a site for it to show up there. Let me check, though.

Comment: That does seem to be the case.

Comment: Regarding your edit: see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299602/unable-to-update-user-profile-on-stack-overflow-this-email-address-is-already-r?s=1|151.5903

Answer (score 1):

The network reputation graphs *only* show sites that have more than 200 reputation

On my own account

[image]

Here are the sites that are hovering around 200 reputation

The axis seem wrong the - those sites *start* at 101 reputation then go up, but you can't see SO, at 198 reputation.

[image]